# Concat all js files inside a folder using NPM concat using CLI

Tags: javascript, npm, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate all my `js` files inside a folder using NPM package called `concat` in command line.

The code That I have came up with is:
`concat -o js/scripts.js js/inc/*.js` but it doesn't work, however after changing it to the individual filenames like: `concat -o js/scripts.js js/inc/nav.js js/inc/ads.js` it works.

This is a part of `package.json`

```
"js": "concat -o js/scripts.js js/inc/_nav.js",
"html": "pug templates/pages -o . -E html --pretty",
"build": "npm-run-all js css html"
```

If it doesn't work the ways in this way and I am required to utilize a new package using `cli` I appreciate it if you could introduce that with a sample.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you're looking for help with a specific npm package you might have better luck asking directly on their tracker.

Comment: what command line are you using? bash or cmd or powershell or other?

Comment: Doesn't really matter which one npm is standalone ... But assume bash